# Tomcat 7 service manual start, stops immediately on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, tomcat, windows-service

I have just performed a fresh installation of Tomcat 7 (apache-tomcat-7.0.30) using the 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer available [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi), on my local Windows 7 PC.

Yet, when I go in Service to start it manually, it starts and stops immediately after displaying the following message:

[image]

I have noticed that each time I try, I get the following lines in my tomcat-7-stdout log:

```
2012-09-16 18:41:12 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

Anyone knows what is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it. For some unknown reason, my Java JRE6 was corrupted. I reinstalled it manually and the issue disappeared.